# How can I show the connecting line in treeview of nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

I want to display the line that connect childNode with parent of treeView itmes. Same as unchecking the "Display simple folder view in Explorer's Folders list" in Windows-XP's Folder Options like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: // I use ubuntu v12.10 64bits

Answer (score 1):

Nautilus has an option for enabling tree view.  To enable it open: `View -> Sidebar` and select tree.

[image]